# How to get arraylist contain position?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I am making an application for android.I have a customized listview and this view"s items came to my database.I want to update new value.This value come to listview after database is updated. My problem is ;When new value come to database, My layout is refreshing yourself.But How can I get contain value"s position? If I get value"s position ,I will put the color on convertView at same position?How can I do it ?

```
       class OyunTextView extends BaseAdapter {


            @Override
            public int getCount() {

                return  listData.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return listData.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.oyuntextview, null);
                TextView namesbox = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.isim);
                sayılar = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sayı);
                namesbox.setText(listData.get(position));
                sayılar.setText(listDataoran.get(position));

//I have tried here.

    if (listDataoran.contains("60")){
      String deger ;
        listDataoran.in

        switch (position){
            case number of positon at listDataoran.contains("60"): convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yirmi));
                break;

        }

    }


                return convertView;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whene you add value to listData use listData.add(your value, index) the use notifydatasetchanged foe your adapter finally color your view in the index position

Comment: I dont use notifydatasetchange because it's useless for me when update data layout is not refreshing so  when list updated(from mdatabase.update method) I need to know new value where is at my column that ı am going to refresh color of the listview "s line.I have edited my question.